# How to share an Ethernet connected printer on different home networks via Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

I’ve got the following network system at home:

[image: Network diagram.]

The Wi-Fi devices we use are [TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR1043ND.html) routers. A little explanation: We have a 3 story high building and instead of using repeaters, we use separate wireless routers to make sure each floor has a strong connection. Might be a bit silly but okay, I didn’t make the decision on this one. Every floor is equipped with a LAN connection—wireless routers are connected to these ports—which is connected in the basement with the switch; a [TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-41_TL-SG1024DE.html). Now, in the basement we have our printer ([Dell 1355cn Multifunction Color Printer](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/dell-1355cn/pd)) also connected to the switch via Ethernet.

I’d like to use the printer when my computer is connected to any of my Wi-Fi devices. I just don’t really know how to. I’ve been searching around on the internet but I can’t seem to find what I’d like to do. I don’t really like to set up a computer as a printer server unless I’m sure that is the only way that this would work.

Comment: Are the "wifi devices" acting as routers (with or without NAT) or pure bridges? If they're configured as proper access points (not routers), then this question wouldn't be necessary, since there would be just _one_ network.

Comment: My apologies for my lack of understanding of the terminologies. 
The wifi-devices are wireless routers. I also assume that they are configured as such, not as access points.

Comment: Yes, it is a network printer that connects over ethernet. Dell 1355cn to be precise.

Comment: I don't think we can get any further without knowing more about how the wireless routers are configured. Can you reconfigure them, if that's what a solution requires? As @grawity suggests, the easiest solution is to run them all as access points. If you can't, then you should look at the IP configuration when connected to each of them, and note the IP address, network mask and gateway address. It would also be helpful to know the operating systems involved and whether you are using IP4, IP6 or both.

Comment: I know that I need to make the wireless routers communicate with the switch. I just don't know how. What settings do I need to change in the wireless routers? 

So, changing them to access points is a solution? I'll check this.

Yes, they are reconfigurable. IPv4 and 6 both. However, there is still some conflict between the router of the provider and our switch. But that is a different problem. Perhaps this will be solved once I reconfigure them as access points?

OS involved: Windows 10, Windows 7, Android Marshmallow and Lollipop, iOS 9 and OSX El Capitan. I don't think this helps?

Answer (score 1):

### CONNECTING TO A NETWORK CONNECTED PRINTER

***(See shared PC printer section below too - Two sections for each method)***

In a nutshell and brief. . .

**1.** Get your networked printer configured so it's TCP/IP properlties
   match those for your netowrk, and then get it connected to the
   network switch—assuming not DHCP or MAC reservations, etc..

**2.** From a PC on that same network, define a printer on that PC as a standard TCP/IP printer, load the drivers, etc. as usual, and it should populate and then be a printer you're able to print to when that PC is connected to the network, the printer is connected and powered on.

**ASSUMPTIONS:** *I'm assuming you're in a mainly Windows environment, and that you're already familar with defining printers on those machines, and that you're capable of defining the TCP/IP properties of your networked printer as well.  In addition, I assume all the connectivity is in place so the devices from all routers in your topology can talk with the devices on the basement switch and/or that you are familiar with those configuration and what to do at this level otherwise or have a network admin to support it or work with on configurations at this level.*

**NOTE:** *I'll be glad to add further steps if needed once you disclose further detail for a more accurate answer.*

---

### **DEFINING THE SHARED PRINTER CONNECTED TO A NETWORKED PC**

For the print server configuration from a PC (presuming basement), you'll need to pick ONE PC to install the printer onto and confirm it works from there locally.  You'll then `SHARE` out that printer, assign it permissions to `EVERYONE` for printing, etc. and then from the other machines that connect to the same network where this SHARED printer and PC are connected.

**WARNING:** *This PC must stay turned on and if it's off, then the shared network printer defined on that machine will not be accessible to the other network devices.*

**ACCESSING THE SHARED PRINTER REMOTELY (same network)**

From [remote] other Windows computers, you could likely just type in `\\PCName\SharedPrintername` or `\\IP Address\SharedPrintername` and then press `Enter` from other machines connected to that network, confirm that they see the printer, double-click on it, and then the drivers from that machine should download and install onto the remote machine, and once down you should be able to print to it.

**Considerations**

- *You may need to manually install the drivers of the printer onto the remote  machines locally if you have to define it manually (meaning the installation fails with the `\\IPAddress\SharedPrintername`), and then point to the drivers from the disc, etc. when it goes to define it at this level. Once the drivers are there, it'd just show up as a printer as usual to pick to print to.*
- *You'll also need to consider and plan for drivers to load onto the printer from    the print server PC for CPU architecture for others devices that'll connect to it such as `x64` and `x86` drivers. Doing this and installing additional drivers up front may help ensure more devices that connect to it via the `\\PCName\SharedPrintername`* may not need to install the drivers from that disc locally, etc..
- *The PC you setup the shared printer on may need to have a static IP if you're not able to resolve it's name with `\\PCName` if only the `\\IPAddress` way works for you in your setup as you don't want to define it when it has one IP it got via DHCP and then it turns around and gets another and then those devices pointing to the old IP address wouldn't be able to print to it.*
- *Ensure your local network and access points, etc. all the TCP/IP traffic to the print server from all or any subnets to get to the PC shared print server.*
- *Ensure the PC shared print server OS (i.e. Windows) allows file and print sharing and/or that the Windows Firewall is not blocking the traffic. Disable the FW to test if you have issues and that'll tell you quickly if it's blocking the traffic at this level.*

**NOTE:** *I'm not adding screen shots here as I assume you're familiar with some of this and I'm also assuming you're doing this from Windows, but if you disclose and add more detail to your question and let me know afterwards, I'll be happy to see what further I can add to clarify more.*